# Mapping texture onto cube in primitives issue

Tags: c#, xna

I recently redid code to draw cubes, with a texture on each face, but I'm having trouble mapping a texture onto each face.
http://imgur.com/a/0sHKq
The top image is what I want the game to look like. 
The bottom image is what it currently looks like.

My code to set up the blocks is as follows.

```
newVertices[0].Position = new Vector3(position.X, position.Y, position.Z);
        newVertices[0].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(1, 1);
        newVertices[1].Position = new Vector3(position.X, position.Y + size.Y, position.Z);
        newVertices[1].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(1, 0);
        newVertices[2].Position = new Vector3(position.X + size.X, position.Y + size.Y, position.Z);
        newVertices[2].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(0, 0);
        newVertices[3].Position = new Vector3(position.X + size.X, position.Y, position.Z);
        newVertices[3].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(0, 1);
        newVertices[4].Position = new Vector3(position.X, position.Y, position.Z + size.Z);
        newVertices[4].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(0, 1);
        newVertices[5].Position = new Vector3(position.X, position.Y + size.Y, position.Z + size.Z);
        newVertices[5].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(0, 0);
        newVertices[6].Position = new Vector3(position.X + size.X, position.Y + size.Y, position.Z + size.Z);
        newVertices[6].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(1, 0);
        newVertices[7].Position = new Vector3(position.X + size.X, position.Y, position.Z + size.Z);
        newVertices[7].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(1, 1);
```

This is the best I could come up with, but there is no texture, or more likely the very corner of the texture, being applied to the top and bottom faces.

My draw code, if that's any use

```
public void Draw(Camera camera)
    {
        effect.View = camera.View;
        effect.Projection = camera.Projection;
        effect.World = rotationMatrix;

        foreach (EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
        {
            pass.Apply();
            graphicsDevice.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives<VertexPositionNormalTexture>(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, newVertices, 0, 8, indices, 0, 12);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If ypu declare only 8 vertices you'll draw only two faces of a cube, not six.

Comment: Do you use drawindexedprimitves without using an IndexBuffer? Where do you set the indices?